# Django related_name

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to do something like:

```
{% for property in current_listing %}
    {% for property_image in property.property_images.all %}

    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But I would like something like:

```
{% for property in current_listing %}
    {% for property_image in property.property_images.**ORDER_BY('-order')[0]** %}

    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You might want to look into using a Manager which could provide you with the ordering and filtering.

Comment: The title does not relate to the actual question. Please change it.

Comment: It would help if you could show us your model classes.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what you want, you can try [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/):

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_first_ordered_by(queryset, order):
    return queryset.order_by(order)[0]
```

Then on a template:

```
{% load my_tags %}

{% with image=property.property_images.all|get_first_ordered_by:'-order' %}
    {{ image }}
{% endwith %}
```

Note, that you can not use {% for %} since result of `get_first_ordered_by` is not iterable.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a method to you Model's class definition that returns the query you want, then cann that method from you template.